# Proof of Jacobi triple product using Ramanujan's notation

Tags: solution-verification, theta-functions

Inspired by this proof in [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html), I rewrote the proof in terms of the [Ramanujan theta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function).

Define the function $$M(c)=\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 +a^{n}b^{n-1}c)\left(1+\frac{a^{n-1}b^{n}}{c}\right)\tag1$$

then $$M(abc)=\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 +a^{n+1}b^{n}c)\left(1+\frac{a^{n-2}b^{n-1}}{c}\right)\tag2$$

$$M(abc)=(1+a^2bc)\left(1+\frac{1}{ac}\right)(1+a^{3}b^{2}c)\left(1+\frac{b}{c}\right)(1+a^{4}b^{3}c)\left(1+\frac{ab^{2}}{c}\right)\cdots$$

$$M(c)=(1+ac)\left(1+\frac{b}{c}\right)(1+a^{2}bc)\left(1+\frac{ab^{2}}{c}\right)(1+a^{3}b^{2}c)\left(1+\frac{a^{2}b^{3}}{c}\right)\cdots$$

Taking $$\frac{M(abc)}{M(c)}=\left(1+\frac{1}{ac}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1+ac}\right)=\frac{1}{ac}$$

yields the following relation $$M(c)=acM(abc).$$

Now define $$N(c)=M(c)\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 -(ab)^{n}).$$

Then  $$N(abc)=M(abc)\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 -(ab)^{n})$$

which becomes $$N(c)=acN(abc).$$

Now expand $N(c)$ in a Laurent series $$N(c)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n}c^{n}.$$

Using the fundamental relation, we have $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n}c^{n}=ac\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n}(abc)^{n}$$

$$=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n}a^{n+1}b^{n}c^{n+1}$$

$$=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}u_{n-1}a^{n}b^{n-1}c^{n}.$$

Which leads to the recurrence relation $$u_{n}=u_{n-1}a^{n}b^{n-1}.$$

$$u_{1}=u_{0}a,$$
$$u_{2}=u_{1}a^{2}b=u_{0}a^{3}b,$$
$$u_{3}=u_{2}a^{3}b^{2}=u_{0}a^{6}b^{3},$$
$$u_{4}=u_{3}a^{4}b^{3}=u_{0}a^{10}b^{6}.$$

Which in general form is $$u_{n}=u_{0}a^{n(n+1)/2}b^{n(n-1)/2}.$$

Now substituting back into the original Laurent series, we obtain $$N(c)=u_{0}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a^{n(n+1)/2}b^{n(n-1)/2}c^{n}.$$

It can easily be shown that $u_{0}=1$, so that we have the Jacobi triple product in terms of the Ramanujan theta function $$N(c)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a^{n(n+1)/2}b^{n(n-1)/2}c^{n}.$$

***Q***:Is this generalisation of the proof correct?

**Revised**: 25 April 2020

Following Somos' critique, I searched around a couple of papers and finally came across the following on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)

Let us set $a=b=q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and $c=1$ and show that the following numerator and denominator

$\frac{1}{u_{0}(e^{2\pi i n^2 \tau})}=\frac{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{2\pi i n^2 \tau}}{\prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}(1-e^{4\pi i k \tau})\left(1+e^{2\pi i (2k-1) \tau}\right)^2}$

are weight 1/2 modular functions under the transformation $\tau = \frac{-1}{4 \tau}$

Since a modular function is 1-periodic $f(q+1)=f(q)$ and bounded on the upper half plane $\tau \to i \infty$, it ought to be constant according to [Louiville's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), therefore the quotient has to be constant such that $u_{0}(q)=u_{0}(0)=1$

Comment: Looks OK to me as far as the calculation goes. However if we have $A = ac, B = b/c$ then we automatically get $$A^{n(n + 1)/2}B^{n(n - 1)/2} = a^{n(n + 1)/2}b^{n(n - 1)/2}c^{n}$$ and the generalization obtained is equivalent to the same old Jacobi Triple product. So at best its a new proof similar to the one given in MathWorld.

Comment: How do you know that $N(c)$ has a Laurent series? How do you know that $M(c)$ infinite product converges? Also it would help if you gave a complete statement of exactly what you are proving.

Comment: @Somos :As you can see I adapted the method of proof exactly from the linked mathworld site above and used a different notation instead.In case there are missing important details,I hope someone will fill them in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof you have is essentially the same as the MathWorld proof
with a few reparametrizing of terms. It stands or falls with the one you are modeling it on. It is similar in the way that Ramanujan's theta function differs from Jacobi's theta function and I commend you for that.

Unfortunately, that proof is flawed. The crux is the step from
$M(c)$ to $N(c)$ in your proof. It comes from nowhere. Why did you multiply by
that infinite product? The same problem arises in the Mathworld proof going
from $F(z)$ to $G(z)$. Without being able to justify $a_0=1$ the proofs are not
complete. Of course, the result is still true, but the justification is missing.

Comment: Perhaps the author of the original proof from mathworld may give his/her side.

Comment: Perhaps. Still, the problem remains to justify the Laurent series $a_0=1$.

Comment: @ Somos:The step from M(c) to N(c) doesn't necessarily need any justification, since the the function N(c) remains invariant under substitution by (abc)

Comment: @ Somos: The  Laurent series at $a_{0}$ can be justified analogously to the following proof in this [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)